# spring boot handling big request body - processing bulk through multithreading

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have one spring boot controllers which recives many users like below

sample json

```
{
  "users": [
    { "name":"john", "age":18, "type":"1"},
    { "name":"kim", , "age":18, "type":"2"},
    { "name":"Fits", "age":18, "type","3"},
  ]
 }
```

request handler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public void Add(@RequestBody List<user> users) throws Exception {

 // Here I am iterating users and writing one by one to different message topic based on the type
 // if any error in the given user while writing to message topic I am storing that user in other DB


}
```

it works well when I have some 100 users in the user list, but if list is big like 1000 etc it takes too much time.
so is there any spring batch job where I can assign to that to perform this?

I just want to return http response code 202 to request and assign this payload to spring batch job

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you expect there to be some existing Batch job definition that will do this for you?  It sounds to me like the logic you want to move to a Batch job is very specific to your own domain and needs and wouldn't just exist in the wild at this point.  If so, are you then really asking "How do I use Spring Batch?"  That question is beyond the scope of this site.  There are, I assume, dozens of documentation sets and tutorials available to teach you how to utilize Spring Batch.  I'd suggest you look there.

Comment: Yes, I want to make utilize of spring batch and add my business logic to that..

Comment: Have you gotten started with an attempt to do this?  Is there code you can show us so we can see what you're trying?  If not, then this is not an appropriate question for this site.  This site seeks to address specific programming issues and problems, not provide training in the use of a whole technology like Spring Batch. Again, I expect there are already many resources available that could help you with this.

Comment: Google "Spring Batch" and you'll be provided with a wealth of potential learning options.

Comment: It's not clear to me what specific question you exactly have. Do you want to know how to start a Spring batch job through a HTTP request? Do you want to know how to write your business logic as a Spring batch job? Do you want to know how to pass parameters from a HTTP request to a Spring batch job?

Comment: Do the iteration in seperate `Thread` and return the status.

Comment: @g00glen00b, I want to know how to pass my users list to spring batch and iterate that list to do my business logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use Spring `Async Task` for long running processes in separate thread, hence wouldn't wait to execute whole request and send response back.

First configure Async task like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsynchTaskConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ProcessUsers-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

And Here you can use Async task in your service for processing users

```
@Service
public class UserProcessingService {


    private final AnotherUserProcessingService service;
    @Autowired
    public UserProcessingService (AnotherUserProcessingService service) {
        this.service= service;
    }

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<User>> processUser(List<User> users) throws InterruptedException {

        users.forEach(user -> logger.info("Processing " + user));
        List<User> usersListResult = service.process(users);
        // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(usersListResult);
    }

}
```

`processUser(User user)` is annotated with `@Async` indicating the method will run in separate thread according to `taskExecutor` configuration provided above. `@EnableAsync` enable `Spring` to run any method in background thread that is annotated with `@Async`.
And make sure your service using async task to process users must be created inside a `@Configuration` class or picked up by `@ComponentScan`. You can customize your `taskExecutor` according to your needs.

Here you can find How [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22009356/5703813) works.

Comment: I have list of users, how to  pass list of users to async task and iterate them one by one  in async task thread pool

Comment: Hi, here If I set the pool size to 10 and and all threads will iterate users list from beginning, how to keep track of the marker , so each thread picks different user from users list

Comment: I need to recive that request and assign to asnyc task then returm 202

Comment: In async task  I process and if any  errors I provide in some asyc way .. Since I am returning 202 I may recive some more request while processing the first one,  so will it be in que or need to  handle them separately..

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/softnrajkumar1994/multithreading-example

**Important**

**1)Instead 1000 users in a single request please send those users list as small chunks**

```
public class ThreadManager {

    private static ThreadPoolExecutor stpe = null;


    static {
         /**
         *
         *  corePoolSize --->the number of threads to keep in the pool, even
         *        if they are idle, unless {@code allowCoreThreadTimeOut} is set
         *        
         *  maximumPoolSize --- >the maximum number of threads to allow in the
         *        pool
         *        
         *  keepAliveTime---> when the number of threads is greater than
         *        the core, this is the maximum time that excess idle threads
         *        will wait for new tasks before terminating.
         *        
         *  unit the time unit for the {@code keepAliveTime} argument
         *  
         *  workQueue the queue to use for holding tasks before they are
         *        executed.  This queue will hold only the {@code Runnable}
         *        tasks submitted by the {@code execute} method.

         */
        stpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1090));
        System.out.println("THREAD MANAGER INTIALIZED SUCCESSFULLY");
    }

    public static void execute(Runnable task) {
        stpe.execute(task);
    }
}
```

**The above class will receive runnable task and executes with the idle threads of threadpool.**

**Sample User class:**

```
 public class User {

    private String name;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public void Add(@RequestBody List<User> users) throws Exception {
        /**
         * Here we are rotating user's list and assigning each and every user into a
         * separate worker thread, so that work will be done parallely
         */
        for (User user : users) {
            try {
                ThreadManager.execute(new UserWork(user));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Custom runnable worker class for working on user object.Do you business implementation in runnable method.

```
  public class UserWork implements Runnable {



    private User user;

    public UserWork(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Please add your businees logic here
// Here I am iterating users and writing one by one to different message topic based on the type
 // if any error in the given user while writing to message topic I am storing that user in other DB
    }

}
```